# Python Combining strings into the shortest possible string?

Tags: python, algorithm, string

If I have a list of strings, I would like to combine them into one string with overlapping characters. If there is no overlapping strings left just add it to the end. Here is an overly simplified version.

```
input = ['one', 'two']
output = 'twone'
```

What i'm looking for as some way to do that with any number of strings in the input list.

Thanks,
giodamelio

Comment: What output are you expecting given the image in your question?

Comment: What are the inputs?  What is the output?  If it's strings, you should be able to skip the picture and just show the strings that come in and the strings that go out.

Comment: If two string have more than one character in common at their beginning and end, should the entire overlap be combined when the output string is created? i.e. `input = ['predicate', 'atelier']`, `output = 'predicatelier'`.

Comment: What do you do with input strings that don't have characters that overlap those from any other strings. You need to clarify your question a little bit more I think.

Comment: Is there a practical purpose for this seemingly arcane requirement?

Comment: @John this reminds me of the infinite ocean game, where this was required for code matching

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't really good enough to give one trivial example. This is just about the most underspecified question of the (lunar) year. However assuming that overlap can occur only the ends, and each word is tested only twice (against each end of the current output), and you want the maximum overlap, this would do the job:

*[Edit after bugfix]*

```
def glue(a, b):
    maxn = 0
    for n in xrange(1, 1 + min(len(a), len(b))):
        suffix = a[-n:]
        prefix = b[:n]
        if prefix == suffix:
            maxn = n
    # BUG: return maxn, a[:-maxn] + b
    # FAILS when maxn == 0
    # EXTRA TEST: ['nil', 'overlap']
    return a + b[maxn:]     


def multiglue(words):
    if not words: return ""
    result = words[0]
    for word in words[1:]:
        nx, rx = glue(result, word)
        ny, ry = glue(word, result)
        result = rx if nx > ny else ry
    return result

tests = [line.split() for line in """
    one
    two one
    one two
    overlap nil
    nil overlap
    toad dog rabbit
    frog ogham
    ogham frog
    hopper grasshopper
    grass grasshopper person
    foooo oooof
    oooof foooo""".splitlines()]

for test in tests:
    out = multiglue(test)
    print test, repr(out)
```

Output:

```
[] ''
['one'] 'one'
['two', 'one'] 'twone'
['one', 'two'] 'twone'
['overlap', 'nil'] 'niloverlap'
['nil', 'overlap'] 'overlapnil'
['toad', 'dog', 'rabbit'] 'rabbitoadog'
['frog', 'ogham'] 'frogham'
['ogham', 'frog'] 'frogham'
['hopper', 'grasshopper'] 'grasshopper'
['grass', 'grasshopper', 'person'] 'grasshopperson'
['foooo', 'oooof'] 'foooof'
['oooof', 'foooo'] 'foooof'
```

Comment: Sorry about being under-specific on the question.

Comment: I tried it and this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks, I ran into that but its fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a modified version of the [Needleman-Wunsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman-Wunsch_algorithm). It's not clear to me from your question what constraints the combined string has to satisfy (does one string have to embed whole in the other, or can characters from one intermingle from characters from the other?), so I won't modify it for you, but that should be enough to get you started at least.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman-Wunsch_algorithm

Also, http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap6.pdf

Comment: That look promising ill check it out. Thanks

Comment: That look like what I need, but when I looked at the page I got veeery confused.(I am a freshman in Algebra 1 :|). Ill try to stumble through it. Thanks again. P.S your link went a little crazy

Comment: Which page? I linked to two. :) Also, what's got you confused?

Comment: The first link .endswith("Needleman") ... looks like you've got an EN DASH instead of a HYPHEN.

Comment: Ah, that's what's got it confused. That's the URL that Wikipedia gave me for that page, endash and all. Fortunately, a hyphen seems to work just as well. I've fixed the links.