# Combining strings to make the shortest output

Tags: java, string, substring

I was looking for help on some pseudo code for my programming homework. The details are found [here](http://www.hpcodewars.org/past/cw4/problems/Genome.html) but to some it up: I receive strings from a file then I need to combine all of them into the shortest possible string. For example ABC AAB CAB could turn into AABCAB because the letters in the strings overlap.

```
 ABC
AAB
   CAB
------
AABCAB
```

I have troubles understanding what logic I can use for this problem. I've thought of splitting the strings by their length-1 until I get a single character then look for that same character(s) in other strings but it wouldn't work that well.

Comment: This is actually a difficult problem. If speed is not an barrier, then you can just brute force all possible overlaps.

Comment: Take a look at this (identical?) question. You can pretend the Python is pseudocode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697508/python-combining-strings-into-the-shortest-possible-string?rq=1

Comment: I think this is different @rajah9, if you read the answer to that question, and the link that OP posted here there is a big difference in requirement

Comment: @Cruncher good point, and you made me slow down and read the OP's link. In the post that I referred to, one response cites the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm. This could be helpful to the OP. Also, the accepted answer has the code to turn ['toad', 'dog', 'rabbit'] into 'rabbitoadog'; I believe this would be a pretty good response to the base pair subsequences becoming "GATCGGCAGC".

Answer (score 1):

This is rather inefficient but this should work:

```
String findShortestOverlap(String total, ArrayList<String> stringsLeft)
{
    if(stringsLeft.size() == 0) return total;
    String shortest = "";
    boolean first = true;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < stringsLeft.size() ; i++)
    {
         //combine stringsLeft.get(i) with total and call it newTotal. That is find the biggest overlap between these 2 strings.
         newTotal = findShortestOverlap(newTotal, /*copy of stringsLeft with the ith string removed*/);
         if(first || newTotal.length() < shortest.length())
         {
             first=false;
             shortest=newTotal;
         }
    }
    return newTotal
{
```

I haven't tested this. I would also assume more efficient algorithms exist, but this was my brute force shot at it.

Finding the biggest overlap between 2 strings should be an easy problem, which is what this breaks the problem down to.

The first call to this method should have `""` as total.

The easiest way to gain some easy efficiency on this is to save a "global" variable outside of this function holding the "shortest" string found so far. Then only call `newTotal = findShortestOverlap(...)` if newTotal is shorter than the shortest string you found so far. This can cut a lot of brances off of the tree, and if you find a near-optimal solution early in the algorithm, it should go pretty quick from there.

Comment: Thank you for your response, ill be testing the code soon and ill get back to you. I'm also looking at the "identical question," thanks again guys.

Comment: @KhalobC edited with a potential idea for speeding it up a little bit.

Comment: using your code i got this as my output: 
GATCCAGCATCGGCAGTCGG
AAACGTATCGATGCATTATCGATGCATCGATCCTTGCTGAAACGTATCAGCTTGCTGAAACGTA

Comment: @KhalobC Could you provide the exact code you're using? (perhaps a pastebin link)

Comment: @KhalobC `newTotal = stringsLeft.get(i) + total;` is not a sufficient implementation of "combine stringsLeft.get(i) with total and call it newTotal. That is find the biggest overlap between these 2 strings."

Comment: I've been trying to understand what you meant. Here is the code i currently have, am i headed in the right direction? Sorry im not the best programmer..

http://pastebin.com/B1vn4GCh